# What is the longest suspension ever imposed in any major league in football?

Tags: football, trivia

What is the longest ban ever imposed in any major league in football (excluding life bans)? Please provide the offence and the duration of the ban.

Answer (score 3):

The longest ban excluding life ban is of ***[18 months ban](http://tsmsportz.com/football/longest-players-bans/)*** of [Joey Barton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joey_Barton).

> Professional footballers are not allowed to bet on football, any football. But Joey Barton did repeatedly and consistently between 2006 and 2016, making a total of 1,260 bets during that time, including on matches in which he actually played.
>
> Having been found guilty by the FA in April 2017, 34-year-old Barton was fined £30,000 and banned from all football activity for a period of 18 months, ...

[Source](http://www.90min.in/posts/4921716-11-of-the-longest-bans-in-football-history-where-does-joey-barton-rank)

> ... The English star is now serving an 18 months ban from all football activities. This time he did what professional footballers are not allowed to do. FA found him guilty of betting between 2006 and 2016. In fact, he had placed 1,260 bets in that period. He was found guilty on April 2017, fined £30,000 and banned. ...

[Source](http://sokkaa.com/2018/01/04/banished-top-7-longest-bans-time-football-history/2/)

---

***Excluding the cases***:

- [Don Revie - 10 years ban](http://sokkaa.com/2018/01/04/banished-top-7-longest-bans-time-football-history/2/)

> The FA tried to impose a 10-year football ban on legendary former Leeds manager Don Revie at the end of his time in charge of the England national team in the late 1970s. ...
>
> It was only ***overturned in court*** after the FA was deemed to have exceeded its power.

[Source](http://www.90min.in/posts/4921716-11-of-the-longest-bans-in-football-history-where-does-joey-barton-rank)

- [Enoch West- 30 years ban](http://sokkaa.com/2018/01/04/banished-top-7-longest-bans-time-football-history/2/)

> ...  ***initially banned for life*** over match fixing allegations in a game in 1915.
>
> ... West, meanwhile, remained banned from football until 1945 when his suspension was finally lifted. He was 59-years-old by then.

[Source](http://www.90min.in/posts/4921716-11-of-the-longest-bans-in-football-history-where-does-joey-barton-rank)

Comment: A six month ban suspended for three years means he wasn't actually banned at all, unless and until he had another violation within the three year period. This is a different thing from suspension as a synonym for ban itself.

Comment: @Nij Was having problem with understanding whole suspension and ban thing. So, thank you for that. See, updated answer.